# What is "Solution" in BFS search

Tags: search, artificial-intelligence, breadth-first-search

I am studying Artificial Intelligence: A Modern Approach 3rd Edition by Russel. 
On page 82, there is a pseudocode for BFS search. The code is almost clear except the part for "Solution". What is solution? We have Solution(Node) and Solution(Child).

Can someone please explain what that means?
Thanks.

Edit: Here is the code from the book:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/a6irvl0f81hhxpz/bfs--.PNG?dl=0

Comment: Can you at least provide the pseudocode.

Comment: @Jack1987 Sure. I added the link.

Comment: In a breath first search you visit all vertices in a graph looking for a node that satisfies a property. Solution(X) indicates the vertice that satisfies the property, e.g. solution is the vertice you were looking for.

Comment: The `Solution()` function is defined on page 79 of your book: "we use the SOLUTION function to return the sequence of actions obtained by following parent pointers back to the root."

Comment: @RobW Can you please provide me a pseudocode regarding Solution()?